# Can't seem to get $http service to work with AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

Update: Cleaned up the JSON and now it seems there's an issue with the filter...

See original message below..

I am a Javascript newbie and so I am trying to understand why my application is not working.

**My goal with this application is to show TWO upcoming events from a JSON feed residing on the same server.** . Here is **[my live demo](http://ogmda.com/sandbox/listings.html)**.

Here's how I have it set up:

**My view:**

```
<body ng-app="listApp">

<div class="container" ng-controller="EventController">

<h3>Upcoming events:</h3>

    <ul ng-repeat="event in events | upcomingEvents | limitTo: 2">
        <li>{{ event.title }}</li>
        <li>{{ event.start }}</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**My module, controller, and filter:**

```
var app = angular.module('listApp', []);

app.controller('EventController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('events.json').success(function(data) { 
            $scope.events = data;
    })
});

    app.filter('upcomingEvents', function () {
return function (input) {

    var upcomingEvents = [];

    upcomingEvents = input.filter(function (data) {
        var currentDate = new Date();

        if ((data.start - currentDate) >= 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

    upcomingEvents.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.start - b.start;
    });

    return upcomingEvents;
  };
});
</body>
</html>
```

**Sample events from JSON file:**

```
[
  {
    "title": "All Day Event",
    "start": "2015-07-13",
    "allDay": true
  },
  {
    "title": "Long Event",
    "start": "2015-07-05",
    "end": "2015-07-13"
  },
  {
    "title": "Repeating Event",
    "start": "2015-07-15",
    "allDay": false
  },
  {
      "title": "first time",
      "start": "2015-07-31"
  }
]
```

if I remove the $http service and just manually feed the JSON event object into the controller, it will work correctly. It's just that once i put in the $http service, it backfires.

Anyone have any leads on how to fix? Thanks!

Comment: What do you actually have in your JSON? `new Date(...)` isn't something you can put in a JSON string. Plus of course the field names have to be quoted in the JSON.

Comment: You also forgot to add a semicolon after your http request.

Comment: Are there any error messages or anything?

Comment: @skubski, the semicolon is optional unless you are using some sort of Javascript lint program that insists you use it. More significant here would be the absence of `.error(...)`.

Comment: I pretty much run every line through lint, but sure it is nitpicking in this case. (But it can result in very strange behaviour thus making it a good habbit to do so) I do agree that missing an `.error()` is more significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe as "Sample events from JSON file" is a Javascript data structure, but it isn't valid JSON.

See http://json.org/ for the full definition of JSON, but basically you can have strings and numbers, not dates, and the key names must be enclosed in double-quotes, and strings may only use double quotes around them, not single quotes.

You can always validate your JSON by entering it in http://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: Thanks, I cleaned it up a little, but still no-go. Looks like issue with the filter now? http://ogmda.com/sandbox/listings.html

Comment: That should be a separate question. You have an error message in the browser console though so should be able to work something out from the debugger.